# Compile a sass bundle file to a separate css file

Tags: node.js, webpack, sass

I've got a folder for sass modules, that has a main.scss file that bundles together the above mentioned modules. So the main.scss file might look something like this:

```
@import 'base/_base.scss'
@import 'abstracts/_mixins.scss'
```

... and so on.

What I'm trying to accomplish with webpack is to compile the main.scss file to CSS and save it to a diffrent file ( lets call it style.css ) that lives outside the sass modules folder.

Here is my webpack.config.ts, but it doesnt seem to 'update' the style.css when I change main.scss.

```
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: path.resolve('src/js/main.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
            'devtools',
            'src'
        ],

        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            })
        }]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css')
    ]
}

export default config;
```

Comment: Do you have an import/require for your main.scss file? If not you can put one in your main.js or include it in your entry point config object